# How to dynamically auto-register C function so it could be available through the whole project without any imports/headers/externs/.pch-files?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, runtime

In my project I have an doSomething.m and soSomething.h files with the only C function:

```
void doSomething() {

}
```

The **first question**: what should I do to make this function accessible from any place in my code without needing to import any headers?

Note: *I guess that to solve this problem the doSomething.h file is not needed at all, but its presence/absence is not a restriction.*

I have the following pieces of knowledge but I can't have the whole picture of what is needed:

- I can use some another function with **attribute((constructor))** that will be run at compilation runtime and it could do some manipulations to register *doSomething*;
- _class_addMethod_ adds methods on "runtime". But I don't know how to resolve "the class of global namespace";
- NSObject's *+ load* method but it is not relevant here.

The **second tricky question** on top of the first: when I will have an answer to the first question, how can I then prevent "Implicit declaration of function 'doSomething' is invalid in C99" exactly for the function *doSomething* and not for the all others?

UPDATE: I forgot to exclude from the consideration the following options:

1. .pch file, global headers
2. The files where I want to use *doSomething* method **should not contain** any additional declarations like *extern void doSomething()*

Answer (score 3):

Well you cant really make it so you dont have to import a header, what you can do however is add the include into your pre compile header

Look in the "Supporting Files" folder in your project.

you will see a file like thise

```
<ProjectName>-prefix.pch
```

add your import at the bottom of this file. and every file will then have all the imports added here.

**Note**

I use Xcode

I guess if your using another IDE such as for GnuStep you would likely have another place similar. I dont know how the other IDE's work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am aware about this option. Please see, how I've updated my question.

Comment: it sounds like you want something that is not available. Either the code knows about the method, or it does not. You want an Implicit declaration but unfortunately C99 disallows this. either you tell it you have the function available via an extern import, or you import the header with the prototype in it. I dont know of any other way.

Comment: _> it sounds like you want something that is not available._ I know I am asking something tricky, but this is the point of my question.

Comment: perhaps you can take it out of C99 mode. check out `man gcc` in terminal. and check out the -std= section

Comment: if you look in the Target's Build Settings you can find `C Language Dialect` and change it. I dont know that it will help however.

Answer (score 0):

In the file where you want to use it, import it:

```
extern void doSomething (void);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd want to have an answer which does not require _any_ additional declaration/imports at all.